# Remove div class based on the inner h1 value matching to array value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I need to remove the div class block if its inner value h1 does not belong to the array value

For example:

Array:

```
let a = ["List 1", "List 5"]
```

HTML:

```
 <div class="list"><li><h1>List 1</h1></li></div>
 <div class="list"><li><h1>List 2</h1></li></div>
 <div class="list"><li><h1>List 3</h1></li></div>
 <div class="list"><li><h1>List 4</h1></li></div>
 <div class="list"><li><h1>List 5</h1></li></div>
 <div class="list"><li><h1>List 6</h1></li></div>
```

Here I need to check the value of a and display only the div matching the `a[]`

Expected output:

```
<div class="list"><li><h1>List 1</h1></li></div> 
<div class="list"><li><h1>List 5</h1></li></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside loop find your `h1` element  and check your `h1` html value is in array or not using `includes`.

```js
let a = ["List 1", "List 5"];

$(".list").each(function() {
  let txt = $(this).find('h1').html();
  let cf = a.includes(txt);
  if (cf)
    $(this).show()
  else
    $(this).hide()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="list">
  <li>
    <h1>List 1</h1>
  </li>
</div>
<div class="list">
  <li>
    <h1>List 2</h1>
  </li>
</div>
<div class="list">
  <li>
    <h1>List 3</h1>
  </li>
</div>
<div class="list">
  <li>
    <h1>List 4</h1>
  </li>
</div>
<div class="list">
  <li>
    <h1>List 5</h1>
  </li>
</div>
<div class="list">
  <li>
    <h1>List 6</h1>
  </li>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

With filter:

```
$('div').get().filter(n => !a.includes($(n).text())).map(n => $(n).remove())
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried but it is displaying all the data